# Python - What is a simple way to update elements in a list?

Tags: python

Here is an example to illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
class bar:
    pass

list1 = []
for i in range(10):
    bar1 = bar()
    bar1.foo = 0
    list1.append(bar1)


# update list1

for i in range(10):
    print(list1[i].foo)
```

I want the output of the code above to be

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10        
10
10
```

At the `# update list1` part, if I were doing this in C#, I could do

```
list1.ForEach(x=>x.foo = 10)
```

And I know in Python I can do

```
for x in list1:
    x.foo = 10
```

But how can I do it in Python in a way similar to the way in C#?

Comment: Surely a `for in` is the simplest way. Why do you want to use a lambda?

Comment: What's wrong with the for-loop? It's basically the same thing.

Comment: Python deliberately does not provide those tools. Use a `for` loop.

Comment: `for i in list1:   setattr(i, 'foo', 10)`?

Comment: I wouldn't use `map` (which would be similar to for-each with an anonymous function) to mutate objects. Just use the for-loop.

Comment: Thank you guys too for leaving the comments. I have C# background and am new to Python so I am curious to know all the Python counterpart for C# syntax. In C# `List<T>.ForEach(Action<T>)` is preferred to coding a `foreach` loop under some circumstances. Perhaps the difference is not applicable to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the parameter to the initialization; use that in a comprehension.

```
class bar:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

list1 = [bar(10) for i in range(10)]
```

Example for further updating:

```
print([x for x in map(lambda obj:obj.foo + 3, list1)])
```

Comment: you don't need `i` in this case, `list1 = [bar(10) for _ in range(10)]`

Comment: Cool. I thought something like this would be possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to provide an alternative here, but it's also possible to use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) if you define an update function before-hand. This may or may not be suitable for your needs but I wanted to explore this myself :)

```
def update_bar(my_bar):
    my_bar.foo = 10
    return my_bar

list1 = list(map(update_bar, list1))
```